# PHP Mysql Auto Quote?

Tags: php, mysql, string, quotes

When inserting a row in mysql database, string values need to be enclosed in quotes where integer don't need to.

Is there any class or library that takes care of this automatically so that I can just pass to a 3rd-party function an array of fieldnames and values and don't have to worry about putting string values in quotes?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to worry about more than just quoting; you need to worry about SQL injection.

For new code, use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) instead of the `mysql_` or `mysqli_` functions. Within PDO, use prepared statements (the `PDOStatement` object).

With prepared statements, you never have to enclose things in quotes and it stops SQL injections.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [PDO](http://is.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php), then you do not need to worry about things like that.

Take a look at [PDO::prepare](http://is.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm using drupal, the default behavior of `db_query("SELECT col FROM tab WHERE id=%d",$id)` handles that for you.

This is similar to using `sprintf` with `mysql_real_escape_string` on your query first. And you could implement it yourself, from the [code they show](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/db_query/6), note that they use the `preg_replace_callback()` method, and you can click on that..

The traditional way, if you ignore [PDO](http://is.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) (not recommended):

```
<?php
// Connect
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    OR die(mysql_error());

// Query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
?>
```